# Webbrowser module won't open url's

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to open the first ten pages of this website, but the following code does not seem to open the webpages:

```
import webbrowser

url = 'http://www.futhead.com/17/players/?page='
pageNumber = '1'

while pageNumber < 11:
    webbrowser.open(url + pageNumber)
    pageNumber += 1
```

When I try to open the url outside of the while loop, it does work. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing `url + pageNumber` to `url + str(pageNumber)`

Comment: Using a for loop is way more appropriate

Comment: @abccd I am sure it would make a difference - TypeError. But now I see that pageNumber starts out as a string '1' - so the first loop will work OK (at least as far as type checking) but then pageNumber += 1 should fail.

Comment: Yup that's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will throw error because you are trying to increment a string `pageNumber += 1` and you declared it as `pageNumber = '1'`.

```
import webbrowser

url = 'http://www.futhead.com/17/players/?page='
pageNumber = 1

while pageNumber < 11:
    webbrowser.open(url + str(pageNumber))
    pageNumber += 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for this stupid mistake, I'm still a noob ;)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that pageNumber outside of the while loop is a string '1'. However, inside your while pageNumber is treated as a number. I tried running your code as it is and I think the code inside the while loop is never executed (you can test this by putting a print statement inside your while loop).

I think the following code will work:

```
import webbrowser

url = 'http://www.futhead.com/17/players/?page='
pageNumber = 1

while pageNumber < 11:
    webbrowser.open(url + str(pageNumber))
pageNumber += 1
```